# ng-if condition having class name condition

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am using partial view as shown below for each tab.Each partial view has lot of databindings , so now data rendering becomes slow.

```
<div class="tab-content" ng-controller="MyController">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane fade active in " ng-include="'PartialViews/1.html'"></div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-pane fade" ng-include="'PartialViews/2.html'"></div>                            
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane fade" ng-include="'PartialViews/3.html'"></div>                            
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-pane fade" ng-include="'PartialViews/4.html'"></div>                        
    <div id="tab-5" class="tab-pane fade" ng-include="'PartialViews/5.html'"></div>  
</div>
```

In this link it was mentioned like

```
"One approach to using ngIf is to wrap the inner content into a separate partial and ngInclude. If the ngIf condition is false at the outset, then the included partial will not be loaded and evaluated, which will definitely remove its contribution."
```

So i want to use ng-if condition based on active tab(active tab will have class "tab-pane fade active in"). So i need ng-if condition based on class name.(i.e ng-if class name is "tab-pane fade active in"")
But i didnt get how to include class name based expression inside ng-if. Please help.

Comment: How is the switching between partials being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a Controller assigned to your #tab-content. I suggest you add a scope variable keeping track of which view is active, then you can either use `ng-if` or `ng-switch` to only include the necessary views.

Set the model either using `ng-click` (and pass it by a service if the navigation is under another controller) or append a `routeParameter` and set your "activeTab" scope variable using that.

Comment: Worked fine. But no i have a problem . before the all the tabs used to render in the beginning.But now tab is loaded based on click on tabs. Once if i click on all tabs all tabs should be rendered. But if i again go to same tab for which i have visited before then that tab(or partialview) is rendered again. How to avoid it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Could you try to clarify?

Comment: Ok. i have posted new question for that problem. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29817806/angularjs-load-tabs-based-on-active-tabs-but-prevent-rendering-on-visited-tabs/29818123#29818123